# Definition of Clifford Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors, clifford-algebras

I'm currently studying algebras, and in particular Clifford Algebras. Primarily I've been looking at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.11460.pdf), and on page 7 and 8 the definition of a Clifford Algebra is given. I have a broad understanding of tensor algebras, but I'm struggling to understand the definition of Clifford algebra by the quotient algebra $T(V)$ with the ideal $I_q$ where $$I_q = < v \otimes v + q(x)1_{T(V)}>$$ In particular, it isn't clear to me why $I_q$ is a proper ideal, or how to interpret its elements, and further the elements of $T(V)/I_q$. I know this might be a lot of questions all in one, but any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

To try to correct the notation a little, it is usually defined by $$I_q = \langle \{v \otimes v - q(v)1_{T(V)}\mid v\in V\}\rangle$$

Almost every resource on Clifford algebras demonstrates that if you select a basis $e_1, e_2,\ldots e_n$ for $V$, the collection of products of the form $e_{i_1}\cdot e_{i_2}\cdots e_{i_k}$ where $k\geq 0$ and $i_1<i_2<\ldots < i_k\leq n$ (including the empty one that produces $1$ and the ones that are just single elements of the basis) is a basis for the Clifford algebra.  Within that argument is the evidence that the ideal is proper.

This also gives a concrete representation of the elements, as linear combinations of what they call "blades."  It is reminiscent of the tensor algebra itself, except that now it's finite dimensional, of dimension $2^n$.

About interpretation in practice: for one thing, there are multiple interpretations of elements of the Clifford algebra. Some are used to represent what is acted on, some are used to represent what is acting. Depending on the context, one may be using an ordinary linear model, a homogenous coordinate model, or a "conformal model" or something else.  The second thing is that I don't think all elements have interpretations.

Understanding the various ways to use and interpret the algebra elements is a somewhat extensive topic, but fortunately a lot of people have a lot of good texts that attempt to explain the schemes.   I recommend starting with the wiki and then moving on to the numerous open source resources available online.

Comment: I may just not know enough, but I'm missing something in how the basis for the Clifford algebra implies that $I_1$ is a proper ideal. I'm also a little bit confused as to why $I_q$ contains the elements $v \otimes v - q(v)1_{T(V)}$ rather than something along the lines of $v \otimes w + w \otimes v - B(v,w)1_{T(V)}$ for $v,w \in V$ and a bilinear form $B$. I hope I'm not being too ignorant, and I really appreciate the response.

Comment: @EverettPenne (1) If the ideal were improper, the quotient by it would be the zero algebra, so a basis would be empty rather than having $2^n$ elements. (2) The version with $v,w,B$ follows from the version with $v,q$. Contemplate $((v+w)\otimes(v+w)-q(v+w)1)-(v\otimes v-q(v)1)-(w\otimes w-q(w)1$.  (This trick is often called "polarization".)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I appreciate the insight, and that makes quite a bit of sense. Is there a particular reason we know this ideal is two-sided?

Comment: The ideal generated by a set is an ideal by definition.  You are not under the impression that all elements in the ideal are of that form, are you?

Comment: @rschwieb what isn't immediately obvious to me is that $I_q$ *is* an ideal. Of course, I know it is, because many people much smarter than myself worked on and with it, but I'm failing to see why, particularly due to the fact that we can't assume multiplication is associative in general. I hope that explains my confusion.

Comment: @EverettPenne You can assume multiplication is associative because it is associative in $T(V)$. The notation $\langle S\rangle$ means "the ideal generated by $S$". There is nothing to check about it being an ideal: it is an ideal by definition.

Comment: @rschwieb not sure how I made this mistake, but I meant to type commutative instead of associative, sorry for the trouble.